# Вывод краткой и полной новости посредством php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Народ, помогайте! 
Ситуация следующая: в базе данных есть новости, и текст некоторых новостей может достигать 900+ символов. Это довольно много, и хотелось бы что бы в списке новостей отображалась не полная новость,  а краткая, с определенным допустимым количеством символов, а при переходе по ссылке "перейти к новости" открывалась уже новость в полном своем объеме. В принципе как сделать страницу с полной новостью я понимаю, а загвоздка заключается как раз в том, что я просто понятия не имею как сделать новость сокращенной, гуглил долго, не нашел ничего толкового:(

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$short_news = substr($short_news,0,100);
```

Comment: Комментарий выше правильный, но необходимо учитывать кодировку. Если она к примеру utf-8 то нужно использовать mb_substr().

Answer (score 3):

Если в новости есть HTML теги - то необходимо применять более сложные алгоритмы, чем просто substr. Как минимум нужно закрыть теги в полученном результате. Например это делает следующая функция:

```
/*Эта ф-я работает с кодировкой utf-8 , внимание.*/
function close_tags($text_html){
    if (!trim($text_html)) return '';
    $get_string_between = function($string, $start, $end){
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return $string;
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    };
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' .$text_html);
    $doc->encoding = 'utf-8';
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $text_html = $get_string_between(trim($doc->saveHTML()," \r\n" ), '<body>', '</body>');
    return $text_html;
}
```

Тогда:

```
$short_news = close_tags(mb_substr($news_full_text,0,300));
```