# Вопросы безопасности PHP. Фильтрация входящих данных

Tags: php, post, cookie, безопасность, фильтрация

В последнее время начал интересоваться безопасностью создаваемых приложений, интересует несколько моментов связанных с фильтрацией данных в PHP и безопасной аутентификацией/авторизацией. В гуглах нахожу много разной информации, но её не хватает чтобы сделать выводы. Возможно кто-то подскажет или направит на путь истинный, так сказать.

**Главные вопросы:**

- Нужно ли мне фильтровать полностью все входные данные, в т.ч. глобальные массивы `$_SERVER`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, даже при условии что они не вносятся в базу данных. Какие общие моменты мне стоит учесть?
- Чем лучше пользоваться `filter_var()`, `filter_input()`и т.д., или использовать регулярные выражения. Или когда лучше использовать одно вместо другого.
- Какой метод авторизации на сайте можно считать безопасным?
- Используя PDO, могу ли я не боятся связывать переменные сразу (я так никогда не делал, просто интересно, насколько безопасны такие действия) `bindValue(':param', $_POST['value']);`
- Если у меня есть HTML(wysiwyg) редактор, то нужно мне перед сохранение в БД использовать функции `htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` и `htmlspecialchars_decode($var, ENT_QUOTES);`.

**Что у меня сейчас:**

***Авторизация*** на сайте происходит так: Пользователь вводит логин/пароль. Идет запрос на сервер и пытается получить данные (id, пароль, уникальный хеш пользователя) по указаному логину. Если такой есть, то проверяется пароль функцией `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`, и в случае успеха создаются куки, и новый хеш для пользователя:

`$user_hash = md5( md5( time() + time() * rand(2, 10) ));`
`SessionModel::setCookie('_auth', md5($user_id), AUTH_TIMEOUT);`
`SessionModel::setCookie('_token', $user_hash, AUTH_TIMEOUT);`

Пока что я еще не придумал где и как использовать этот хеш с умом, чтобы подтверждать личность пользователя. Скорее всего безопасностью тут и не пахнет, по-этому и прошу советов.

***Фильтрация данных:***

Недели две назад полностью перешел ООП и начал использовать PDO, до этого использовал `mysqli` для соединения, соответственно чтобы очищать входящие данные, я писал свои функции, типа:

```
function clear($var) {

    $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB) or die( mysqli_error($link));
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlspecialchars($var);
    $var = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($var));
    mysqli_close($link);

    return $var;
}
```

Сейчас я вообще не использую фильтрацию для входящих данных, кроме как для html кода, для этого я использую

`$encoded = htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

`$decoded = htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($var, ENT_QUOTES), ENT_QUOTES);`

Последняя повторяется еще раз затем, что с первого раза оно почему-то нормально не отображало расшифрованные сущности, не знаю почему, но чисто случайно таким способом заработало. Остальные данные я принимаю как-то так:

`$title = $_POST['title'];` - иногда использую `trim()` чтобы убрать пробелы :))

***В общем***, понимаю что вряд ли на каждый из вопросов получу здесь развернутый ответ, но был бы очень благодарен, даже за актуальную на сегодняшний день статью с ответами или ответом на такие вопросы. Изучаю PHP уже где-то 1.5-2 года, а на самые простые вопросы (или не простые), ответов не знаю. В гугле же найти подобное трудно, как показала практика.

И буду рад общим рекомендациям :) Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Нужно ли мне фильтровать полностью все входные данные

Вы обязаны не доверять любым данным, полученным извне. Например, $_GET, $_POST (по-умолчанию они вдвоём составляют $_REQUEST, по настройкам `php.ini` `request_order` и `variables_order` сюда же могут входить куки, $_SERVER и переменные окружения), $_COOKIE, $_FILES, данные загружаемые со сторонних систем (например, по API). Общий момент - вы должны искать не абстрактный фильтр от опасных данных, а понимать, какие данные вы рассчитываете обнаружить в этом месте и что с этими данными будет происходить дальше. Вывод в CSV, HTML или запись в СУБД - каждый требует своей особой обработки.

> Чем лучше пользоваться filter_var(), filter_input() и т.д., или использовать регулярные выражения.

Всем, что позволит вам убедиться в корректности данных. Начинать надо с белого списка. Нередко вы заранее знаете, что, например, $_GET['index'] у вас может быть только `foo` или только `bar`. Вот на эти два допустимых значения и проверяйте.

Например, для email пользователя есть штатная регулярка, скрытая в `filter_var`. Это хорошая отправная точка и обычно будет работать хорошо. "Обычно" - потому что email очень уж забавная вещь. Если почитать соответствующие RFC, то окажется, что проще проверить на содержание символа @ и отправить-таки письмо, чем разбираться во всём многообразии допустимых вариантов. Допустимо там практически всё.

Для, например, логина, вы можете пожелать ограничить ввод только латинскими буквами и некоторыми спецсимволами. Это проще всего делается регуляркой.

Самая широкая трактовка, обычно, для свободного текстового ввода. Например, вот для этого самого сообщения. Как правило, допустимы любые символы UTF8.

Кстати, раз завёл речь об этом: пожалуйста, никак не валидируйте пароль, кроме разве что по минимальной длине. И только если того однозначно требует предметная область, то по минимальной сложности. Но ни в коем случае не ограничивайте максимальную. Вам всё равно его хэшировать, а не хранить, пусть пользователь вводит то, что ему нравится и той длины, которая ему нравится.

> Какой метод авторизации на сайте можно считать безопасным?

В зависимости от требования к безопасности. ЭЦП довольно сложно обойти (образно, банковская сфера). Сложно обойти, если авторизация разрешена только с одного конкретного IP одной конкретной VPN (корпоративные данные). Для сайта не столь чувствительного к безопасности - HTTPS (при верной настройке серверной стороны! За прошедшие года неправильно настроить HTTPS стало довольно просто) адекватно прикроет от MitM и зашифрует данные.

Можно хэшировать исходный пароль на клиенте и передать хэш на сервер, чтобы исходный пароль вообще по сети не передавался.

Без HTTPS? Сделайте HTTPS, времена дорогих сертификатов уже в прошлом.

> Используя PDO, могу ли я не боятся связывать переменные сразу

SQL инъекции в этом случае нет. И сразу же важная оговорка: только если у вас корректно настроена кодировка соединения либо отключена эмуляция подготовленных выражений. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection

Но логические ошибки вы проверять всё равно должны. Например, как думаете, использовать (int) $_POST['amount'] безопасно в качестве :amount?

```
UPDATE users SET balance = balance - :amount WHERE id=:user
```

(пример, реально в таком месте будет двойная бухгалтерская запись, которая check'ом дополнительно валидируется элементарно на уровне записи в субд (особенно если бы тот же mysql вообще умел делать check) но как говорит один ДБА, на деньгах люди понимают быстрее).

А если передать -100? Получим начисление денег вместо списания?

> Если у меня есть HTML(wysiwyg) редактор, то нужно мне перед сохранение в БД использовать функции

Очень интересный вопрос и поведение зависит от степени доверия. Вы доверяете тому, кто этим редактором пользуется? Т.е. на выходе должен быть реальный HTML и его необходимо выводить как HTML? Это частая вещь для админки какой-нибудь CMS. Тогда вы валидировать это поле не должны вообще никак. `htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` должен вызываться для этого текста при подстановке в textarea, иначе случайный  в тексте сломает всё.

Если вы не доверяете, но там будет HTML - то вы обязаны досконально разбирать на лексемы и проверять по белому списку весь переданный HTML. Конкретных инструментов не подскажу, знаю только, что есть такие. Проблема в том, что, например, вы хотите дать возможность вставлять `<img src>`, а вам подсунут какой-нибудь `<img src='...' onload="alert(document.cookie)">` и всё, приехали. Вместо безобидного alert может быть и что поинтереснее. А htmlspecialchars нельзя, иначе и картинки не будет тоже.

Если HTML быть не должно вообще - то htmlspecialchars. Можно перед записью в базу применять, а логически уместнее применять непосредственно при выводе в HTML. Но не strip_tags. Почему это вы удаляете то, что пользователь ввёл? Вы должны это верно сохранить и верно показать, а не удалять.

> Если такой есть, то проверяется пароль функцией password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Это ошибка в вопросе? password_hash ничего не проверяет. Проверяет password_verify.

Зачем вы что-то ой как далеко не CSPRNG пишете, судя по всему, в куки и как планируете использовать потом - я тоже не представляю.

CSPRNG - криптографически стойкий генератор псевдослучайных чисел.

Для сессионной авторизации сессии и используйте. Напомню только про один очевидный подводный камень, на который не всегда обращают внимание: у сессии нет времени жизни. Вообще нет. Есть только величина времени от последнего обращения к этой сессии, после которой эту сессию может удалить сборщик мусора. А когда сборщик мусора запустится - да кто его знает. И всё это время сессия всё ещё валидна. Поэтому если для вашей задачи необходимо инвалидировать авторизацию через час после авторизации или после последнего обращения пользователя - эту логику вы должны сделать сами.

Для долговременной авторизации - по-моему, этот ответ и так уже огромен. Лучше отдельным вопросом.

> Фильтрация данных:

См. начало ответа. Вы должны знать, что вы хотите найти в этих данных и куда эти данные пойдут потом. Остальное к безопасности не относится, лишь костыли и иллюзии безопасности. Какой-то магической функции "сделай мне правильно и безопасно" нет.

И разумеется, вы не можете быть уверены, что такие данные вам вообще пришли. Сначала проверяйте на isset или, если допустимо для значений, empty. Или filter_input, он тоже корректно среагирует на отсутствующие ключи.

И раз тут уже про CSRF напомнили: запомните, что всё, что изменяет состояние системы - должно делаться через POST, PUT, PATCH или DELETE запросы (если речь не об API, то обычно используется только POST) и быть прикрыто уникальным токеном. Уникальным вообще или уникальным для пользователя или для сессии - вопрос уже дискуссионный. GET же запросы должны информацию только читать. Два одинаковых GET-запроса должны возвращать идентичный результат. От этого правила иногда приходится отступать, например для ссылки "отписаться от рассылки" в письмах (изменяет данные о подписках), но это именно исключение. Не надо делать удаление чего-нибудь через GET-запрос.

Answer (score 3):

> Нужно ли мне фильтровать полностью все входные данные, в т.ч.
>   глобальные массивы $_SERVER, $_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, даже
>   при условии что они не вносятся в базу данных. Какие общие моменты мне
>   стоит учесть?

Главное, что надо уяснить в web-безопасности: **в запросе может придти что угодно**. Поэтому фильтрация - в зависимости от задачи, много тут говорить бесполезно - есть целые книги об этом. В PHP-фреймворках есть много инструментов для фильтрации: например из входящего HTML можно выпилить все скрипты и on* аттрибуты. Но зачастую более эффективно и читаемо приведение `$id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? (int)$_REQUEST['id'] : 0;` . Фильтровать всё всё в цикле предварительно - не нужно, т.к. это невозможно сделать универсально(кому-то понадобятся кавычки в тексте, кому-то целый HTML, кому-то бинарные данные), а вот фильтровать в контроллере всё что нужно контроллеру - стандартный подход.

> Используя PDO, могу ли я не боятся связывать переменные сразу

Можно конечно. Если правильно использовать. Другой отвечатель [указывал на уязвимость](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example), но это не уязвимость - а кривое использование: **в строку SQL-запроса напрямую ни ключи, ни значения массивов HTTP-запроса не вставляют**, как раз по причине того что в них может быть всё что угодно. А ещё лучше использовать построитель запросов SQL из фреймворка (он может юзать адаптер на выбор - PDO, mysqli, doctrineDBAL, ...) - удобнее, красивше, [почитайте](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/ru/zend.db.select.html) - уверен вам понравится, эта статья по старой версии, но сама статья лучше написана(чем [статья по новой версии](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html)) и на русском, версии практически не отличаются.

> Чем лучше пользоваться filter_var(), filter_input()и т.д., или использовать регулярные выражения. Или когда лучше использовать одно вместо другого.

Удобнее пользоваться классами из фреймворков - например [Zend\InputFilter](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html) или  [yii\base\Model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html) . Ну гораздо приятнее, не знаю как yii - а в zend-е необязательно тянуть весь фреймворк, можно стянуть только один компонент [Zend\InputFilter](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html) и использовать.

> Какой метод авторизации на сайте можно считать безопасным?

Главное через HTTPS. И ещё заметка ввиду популярности md5 - токены, использующиеся при авторизации не должны генерироваться только с помощью md5 , иначе это [небезопасно](http://www.cmd5.ru/).

> Если у меня есть HTML(wysiwyg) редактор, то нужно мне перед сохранение
>   в БД использовать функции

Думаю не стоит, если ты потом на сайте выводишь HTML. НО если юзера могут постить на сайт HTML - из него перед записью в БД: должны вычищаться скрипты, on* аттрибуты, и прочий небезопасный контент. Ещё перед сохранением HTML в БД - круто бы [выправлять битый HTML, закрывать теги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568832/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-php/568854#568854).

P.S. И да - я фанат фреймворков, они экономят кучу времени и нервов.

Answer (score 2):

> Нужно ли мне фильтровать полностью все входные данные, в т.ч. глобальные массивы

$_REQUEST подделка это [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межсайтовая_подделка_запроса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)

$_GET, $_POST - их легко можно подделать, тут не надо объяснять

$_SERVER - Часть значений этого массива заполняется из пришедших http-заголовков. Как вы понимаете в некоторых заголовках специально можно прислать всё что угодно. В частности все, что в массиве $*SERVER начинается с HTTP** можно подделать.

$_COOKIE на сервере не подделать насколько я помню без взлома сервера. PHP создаёт куку со случайным значением — идентификатором сессии, и файл соответствующий этой куке. Подделать (или украсть) можно только эту куку.

> даже при условии что они не вносятся в базу данных

Сложно сказать, зависит от степени критичности, например я подменил свой HTTP_REFERER и меня система редиректнула не туда куда надо. Если всё правильно сделано я попаду на 404 страницу и ничего не случится.

> Чем лучше пользоваться filter_var(), filter_input()

Для всех числовых значений чисто intval() только на 0 проверить не забудьте. Для текста я предпочитаю регулярки.

> Используя PDO

В PDO безопасны только подготовленные запросы и то и через них инъекцию смогли сделать https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example так что htmlspecialchars и addslashes по-видимому пока с нами

> нужно мне перед сохранение в БД использовать функции htmlspecialchars

Да, потому что можно посмотреть куда редактор отправляет данные и послать туда прямой запрос с неверными данными.

> Сейчас я вообще не использую фильтрацию для входящих данных, кроме как для html кода, для этого я использую

Надо использовать подготовленные выражения это основная сила PDO:

```
// Подготавливаем запрос
    $b=$pdo->prepare(" INSERT INTO `table` SET uid=:uid, uri=:uri ");
// Биндим параметры
    $b->bindParam(":uid", $uid);
    $b->bindParam(":uri", $link);
// Выполняем
    $b->execute();
```

> Пока что я еще не придумал где и как использовать этот хеш с умом

Почитайте на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/184220/ https://habrahabr.ru/post/194972/ и не пытайтесь заглотить всё сразу, если это пока сложно то сделайте по старинке, толкьо хеширование sha256 + соль.

P.S. Раз уж влезли в эту тему то для всех форм, приделывайте защиту от CSRF-атак с помощью токена https://habrahabr.ru/post/235247/ токен должен обновляться при каждом обновлении страницы.

Comment: Это не инъекция, это банальная безграмотность при использовании

Answer (score 0):

Как обычно, все ответы - это коллекция нелепых суеверий и повторение бессмысленных мантр. "Харе Кришна, Харе Рама, Харе Харе, Рама Рама". "Вы обязаны не доверять любым данным, полученным бла-бла", "Данным, полученным от пользователя, доверять нельзя". **Как будто любым другим можно.**

При этом никто даже не упоминает о **нелепости самой постановки вопроса**, про централизованную "фильтрацию" "входящих" данных. И не обращает внимания на функцию, используемую автором. Которая и является идеальным воплощением этих совершенно нелепых идей, не имеющих ничего общего с реальной безопасностью.

#### Безопасность и "фильтрация" - это РАЗНЫЕ вещи

А идея единой "фильтрации" всех данных под одну гребёнку ради "безопасности" - так и вовсе невероятная глупость.

Если в жизни подойти к человеку и спросить, "как обеспечить безопасность?", то он обязательно спросит - от чего конкретно? От пожара, от инфекции, от огнестрельного оружия?

А в программировании почему-то в порядке вещей давать такие обобщенные советы, "Залейте из огнетушителя, наденьте бронежилет, и сверху натяните презерватив. Но только если выходите из общественного транспорта".

Смешно? Погодите смеяться. Самое-то смешное - это что такие советы **вообще никого не удивляют.**

И в итоге получается как у автора: сначала он кодирует данные для HTML чтобы положить их в базу (как будто для БД это имеет хоть какое-то значение), а потом, перед выводом в HTML, он их **раскодирует.** И остаётся только спросить - а в чем был смысл, если данные остались ровно те же самые?

## Безопасность

Две простые вещи, которые надо понимать про безопасность:

#### 1. Не бывает универсальной фильтрации, которая обезопасит данные для любых применений

Любая обработка данных должна быть **адресной**, в зависимости от **контекста использования данных**. Для защиты важно не откуда пришли данные, а *куда они идут,* как используются в данный конкретный момент времени:

- Используем данные в SQL? Защищаемся не в дурацкой функции-франкенштейне (причем задолго до того, как мы узнаем, а будут ли эти данные вообще использоваться в SQL запросе), а строго при выполнении SQL, заменяя все переменные в запросе на символы подстановки
- Выводим данные в браузер? Опять же, защищаемся не в дурацкой функции, а строго при выводе данных. Причем, опять же, **в зависимости от контекста**

  - выводим в HTML? используем `htmlspecialchars`
  - передаем данные в яваскрипт? всегда только через `json_encode`
  - выводим в HTML, передавая данные в яваскрипт? **И то и другое вместе**

    ```
    onclick="<?=htmlspecialchars("window.open(".json_encode($v).")") ?>">
    ```
- используем полученное по ссылке имя файла? Зля защиты применяем по меньшей мере `basename()`, а лучше проверку по белому списку.
- используем данные в контексте XXX? Применяем форматирование данных, специфическое для XXX. Причем не заранее, "про запас", а строго в момент использования

Из правила номер один логично следует правило номер два:

#### 2. Обрабатываться должны ЛЮБЫЕ данные, а не только "пользовательские"

- если у нас в самых невинных данных будет одинарная кавычка, то она поломает SQL запрос.
- если у нас в самых невинных данных будет двойная кавычка, то при выводе в атрибут HTML тега она поломает дизайн страницы
- если у нас данные уже лежат в приложении, изначально они все равно были "пользовательскими". И так ими и остаются. То есть делить данные на "пользовательские" и "не пользовательские" просто ГЛУПО. Любые данные всегда пользовательские. И корректно их надо обрабатывать ВСЕГДА, при любом использовании. А не только "например $_GET, $_POST, которые вдвоём составляют $_REQUEST".

## Валидация ("фильтрация")

Кроме корректной обработки данных в зависимости от контекста, есть ещё такое понятие, как **валидация**. Которая действительно делается на входе, но при этом служит в первую очередь не для безопасности, а для удобства и предсказуемости кода.

Но опять же, невозможно валидировать все данные под одну гребенку. Валидация всегда тоже должна быть **адресной**, но в данном случае - в зависимости от **типа данных**.

- проверка на то, что емейл является емейлом - это валидация
- проверка на то, что введенное значение входит в определенный диапазон (является либо "foo" либо "bar") - это валидация
- проверка на то, что введенное значение является числом - это валидация
- проверка на то, что введенное значение является строкой (а не например массивом, поскольку в как через $_GET, так и через $_POST можно легко передавать массивы) - это валидация

При этом валидация в общем случае не **имеет отношения к безопасности и НЕ ОТМЕНЯЕТ** стандартных правил обработки данных в зависимости от контекста.

При этом в редких случаях валидация все-таки пересекается с безопасностью.

Например, если автор получает с клиента HTML код, то его, разумеется, уже нельзя обезопасить при выводе. Поэтому его надо делать безопасным на входе. прогнав через утилиту типа `HTMLPurifier`. После чего текст станет безопасным в контексте HTML, и его можно будет выводить на HTML страницу без стандартной обработки.

Answer (score -1):

Безопасность - это очень комплексная тема и тут поможет только комплексный подход, который должен быть разработан в соответствии с требованиями к безопасности данных проекта. Хотя есть какие-то общие принципы.

### Данные

**Данным, полученным от пользователя, доверять нельзя.** Фильтровать и валидировать данные следует на определенный запрос в зависимости от требований к данным, универсального решения нет.

Для валидации воспользуйтесь библиотекой какой-нибудь с github, например [respect/validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation), не пишите 500 раз велосипед.

### Безопасная авторизация

Если ставите куку, привяжите ее к IP адресу, user-agent пользователя, куки не должны содержать данных в открытом виде и быть httpOnly, чтобы ее не утащили, а если утащят, то у злоумышленника она будет недействительна. Используйте https для большей безопасности передаваемых данных.

Только в безопасности ли ваш БД-сервер, где будет храниться кука? :)

### PDO

Подготовленные запросы в PDO защищают вас от инъекций, но входные данные на предмет правильности все равно валидировать нужно.

### HTML валидация

Для валидации входящего HTML достаточно создать белый список доступных для пользователя тегов и очищать лишние. [Пример библиотеки](https://github.com/attilammagyar/html-filter), которая позволяет задавать доступные теги, и даже разрешенные атрибуты к каждому тегу.

Comment: Уважаемые анонимные хейтеры, когда минусуете, пишите причину.