# Помогите записать/вырезать двойные/одинарные кавычки в базу sql pdo php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Не могу вырезать или записать в бд текст с кавычками.

Перепробовал и экраны и вырезки. Записывается в базу всё до первых кавычек, остальное нет.

```
<select name="ololo">
<option value="Контора "Рога и котыпа"">1</option>
<option value="Контора 'Рога и котыпа'">2</option>
</select>
```

отправляю это всё на обработку через `ПОСТ`

Ловлю:

```
$ololo = $_POST['ololo'];
```

Записываю:

```
$result = $коннект_с_БД->exec("INSERT INTO таблица (ololo) VALUES ('$ololo')");
```

Comment: а если по-человечески через подготовленные выражения вставлять, то тоже ничего?

Comment: тоже ничего....

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley, идите читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568971/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/186083 про htmlspecialchars() и подготовленные выражения.

Answer (score 0):

ладно, если по-феншую делать лень - то в качестве "абы как" пусть будет:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(..........);
$result = $коннект_с_БД->exec("INSERT INTO таблица (ololo) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $ololo)."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO таблица (ololo) VALUES (%s)",
    $коннект_с_БД->quote($ololo)
);
$result = $коннект_с_БД->exec($sql);
```

Comment: Режет всё после кавычек

Comment: У вас наверное через форму значения не пересылаются полностью.

Comment: Можно подробнее немного

Comment: Кавычки должны быть заэкранированы.
<option value="Контора &quot;Рога и котыпа&quot;">1</option>
Для экранирования используйте функцию htmlspecialchars.

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!! Сделал в опшене и работает!!!! value="'.htmlspecialchars($blabla).'"

Answer (score 0):

Первое, хоть и не по порядку как они в коде идут, но глаз жутко режет.
Да, это очень удобно делать запрос "одной строчкой", но это противоречит схеме работы с PDO.

```
$stmt = $коннект_с_БД->prepare("INSERT INTO таблица (ololo) VALUES (?);");
$stmt->execute([$ololo]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Если очень нравится делать это в одну строчку - сделайте специальную функцию/класс для этого.

Второе, у вас в первом option идёт "Контора "Рога и копыта"" - оно и будет заносить в базу только "Контора " - потому что значение атрибута на этом и заканчивается. Нужно писать внутри атрибутов вместо двойных кавычек: `&quot;`

Если вставляете значения для value в php части - то можно делать вместо подстановки переменной "как есть" вот так:

```
str_replace('"','&quot;',htmlspecialchars($a))
```